# Custom Link URL: Cross-site Scripting Possible cross site scripting attempt detected.

Tags: case, case-object

I have a custom link on Case which is a URL, here is the shortened version:

> /500/e?retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&cas15=Originating%20Service%20Request:%20{!Case.CaseNumber}%0D%0D{!Case.Description}

It creates a new Case from an existing Case and populates Case.Description (cas15) with the old case Id, CaseNumber and Description. However when I click the link I get the following error:

> Cross-site Scripting Possible cross site scripting attempt detected.

I have identified {!Case.Description} as the error in this case; if I remove it I get no errors. I then noted that on one particular Case record that the Case.Description contained a hyperlink i.e. 'You need to login into 'http://www.google.co.uk' first'

If the hyperlink is removed (http://www.google.co.uk), then the custom link below works as desired.

> /500/e?retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&cas15=Originating%20Service%20Request:%20{!Case.CaseNumber}%0D%0D{!Case.Description}

Strangely this only occurs in production and not on any of my sandboxes. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try using URLEncode on the Case.Description

Comment: Actually Case.Description contained more than that; it also contained the string 'Script:' which seems to be the cause of the error.